# ionic - $http.get items from Json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

Console: SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 119

Xcode controller:

```
 str="http://www.website.com/user-orders.php?e="+$scope.useremail;
 $http.get(str)
   .success(function (response){
     $scope.user_orders = response;
     sessionStorage.setItem('userorders_id', $scope.user_orders.id);

     $scope.orders = [
       {  id:  $scope.user_orders.id, 
          uniqueid:   $scope.user_orders.uniqueid,
          platenumber: $scope.user_orders.platenumber,
          paymentstatus: $scope.user_orders.paymentstatus,
          orderstatus: $scope.user_orders.orderstatus 
       }
     ];
    }).error(function() {
      var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Failed to get orders!',
        template: 'Please check your credential'
      });
    });
```

Json:

```
{"records":{"id":"21","uniqueid":"42803122423","platenumber":"00000","paymentstatus":"Success","orderstatus":"Queued"},{"id":"22","uniqueid":"428032438","platenumber":"00000","paymentstatus":"Success","orderstatus":"Queued"},}
```

Template:

```
<ion-content ng-controller="orderslistCtrl">


      <ion-list>
          <ion-item ng-repeat="order in orders" href="#/app/orderslist/{{order.id}}">
         {{order.id}}
            {{order.uniqueid}}
          </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
 </ion-content>
```

If i leave only 1 item in "records" as:

```
{"records":{"id":"21","uniqueid":"42803122423","platenumber":"00000","paymentstatus":"Success","orderstatus":"Queued"}}
```

it shows only 1 result. 
If I load two records it shows error.

Comment: Your JSON response in incorrect. It should be an array which it is not. And there is an extra comma at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Json have been fixed. Error now with accepting values. 

Now it shows:  [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your json file was wrong...because your JSON object {records:{}} which contains records:{} as key as an object if you have n no.of record items you need to show inside an array as below

```
{"records":[{"id":"21","uniqueid":"42803122423","platenumber":"00000","paymentstatus":"Success","orderstatus":"Queued"},{{"id":"22","uniqueid":"428032438","platenumber":"00000","paymentstatus":"Success","orderstatus":"Queued"}}]}
```

Comment: Hi there,

thanks for your suggestion. The error have been fixed with Json on PHP side. But now it just shows nothing, empty values. It seems that:
1. It gets the values as it would alert that it cant get values. 
2. There should be other way to call the items from Json.

Any idea how to get them in other way?

Comment: It shows now:
` [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`

Comment: Alright, so the problem was with "comma" - "," in the latest json object.